# Algorithm that identify same product with (slightly) different names

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, k-means, bayesian

I am mining data from a second-hand camera trading platform.

People give different names to the same products. The data I obtained are as follows:

```
...
Canon 50mm f1.4
Canon 50mm 1.4
Canon 50mm 1.4 USM
Canon 70-200mm f4L
Canon 70-200mm f4 L
...
many more
```

My goal is to train a system to recognize `item 1-3` as one product, while `item 4-5` as another. In my dataset I do not know how many distinct products are there.

I have read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744801/algorithm-to-classify-a-list-of-products-take-2).

It suggests that `Bayesian classification` is useful.
However, given that I do not know how many products are there, I could not provide a training set.

Another answer suggests that `clustering` should be used to group products with similar name. Again, `K-means` can only be used when `K` (the number of distinct products in this case) is known.

So in my case, what algorithm can be used? and could you explain with my data as an example? Thanks!

Comment: Edit distance functions like Damerau-Levenshtein are a possibility. Bigrams are another possibility. But you're asking a pretty broad question. There are practically books on this topic (Record Linkage).

Comment: @hatchet I disagree. "Cannon 1.5" will be classified as much closer to "Cannon 1.4" than "Cannon 1.4 USM" using edit distance. It could be one of the features of the classification or an initial filter, however (but not on its own).

Comment: @amit - you are right. But I expect there are counter-examples for any fuzzy matching technique that is blind to domain specific knowledge. I agree that just using a single off-the-shelf algorithm like that will probably be insufficient. But those algorithms are possibilities for using in a more comprehensive solution. That is why I offered them in a comment instead of an answer.